# Vector optimization challenge: recursive audio filter function

Tags: swift, performance, optimization, accelerate-framework

I'm trying to efficiently replicate Apple's [vDSP_deq22](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_deq22) function (from the Accelerate framework) in Swift without using proprietary code, so I can use it cross-platform.

I've got the function down to a relatively simple loop that looks like this (I was able to mathematically factor out some terms of the original equation):

```
// `input` is a vector of ~1024 Floats between 0 and 1
func filterBuffer(input: [Float]) -> Float {
    // optimization:
    let (b0, a1, a2) = (coefficients[0], coefficients[3], coefficients[4])

    for x in input {
        let y = b0 * (x - scratchSpace[1]) - a1 * scratchSpace[2] - a2 * scratchSpace[3]

        // ... do something with y ...

        // These are the problematic values: previous values of y are used
        // in calculating the current value of y, i.e. the calculation is
        // recursive, which makes it difficult to vectorize.
        scratchSpace[3] = scratchSpace[2]   // y[n-2]
        scratchSpace[2] = y                 // y[n-1]

        scratchSpace[1] = scratchSpace[0]   // x[n-2]
        scratchSpace[0] = x                 // x[n-1]
    }
}
```

This is about twice as fast as the naive (non-factorized) implementation, but Apple's function still runs about 50% faster again (i.e. my version needs 50% more CPU time).

Given the fact that Apple's function is in the Accelerate framework, I'm assuming it uses some kind of SIMD instructions and/or other vectorization tricks.

Following that line of thought, I tried this:

```
// input gets multiplied by `b0` aka `coefficients[0]` and put into inputBuffer
// we saved the last two elements of inputBuffer
vDSP_vsmul(input, 1, coefficients, inputBuffer.advancedBy(2), 1, vDSP_Length(count)

// outputBuffer[n] = inputBuffer[n] - inputBuffer[n - 2]
vDSP_vsub(inputBuffer.advancedBy(2), 1, inputBuffer, 1, outputBuffer.advancedBy(2), 1, vDSP_Length(count))

for n in 2 ..< initedBufferLength {
    outputBuffer[n] -= a1 * outputBuffer[n - 1] + a2 * outputBuffer[n - 2]
}

// outputBuffer now contains the y values from the first loop, perform work on them
```

For some reason this is about 75% slower than the first solution, even though the work performed (in terms of memory accesses, multiplications, subtractions etc) should be the same. In fact, the values of `x[n - 1]` and `x[n - 2]` aren't being shuffled around in each iteration of the loop, so there should be less work performed overall.

Nothing in Instruments gives me any idea of what might be taking so long, the offending line in the vector 'optimized' (but actually slower) version is the `for` loop, taking about 90%+ of the function's CPU time. Given that this loop is simpler than the first one (less terms overall, one less multiplication), I can't see why it'd be slower.

The question is, how can I vectorize the loop to be faster? Theoretically my version should end up faster than Apple's vDSP_deq22, because I can factor out some terms, whereas they must always assume the worst-case scenario in terms of input coefficients.

Comment: The original loop looks like this: `for (n = 2; n < N+2; ++n) C[n] = A[n-0]*B[0] + A[n-1]*B[1] + A[n-2]*B[2] - C[n-1]*B[3] - C[n-2]*B[4];` I was already able to remove two of those terms mathematically though.

Comment: Also, I realise I'm using vDSP functions to replace the vDSP function. This is fine though, because simple vector / vector and vector / scalar operations form the basis of pretty much any SIMD-optimized library, like OpenBLAS. So I'm not concerned about that for now, instead I'd really like to just break down the deq22 function into its component parts and have an equivalent (if not superior - because maths) result.